What's the deal with definitional disputes relying so much on the particulars of language?
Full disclosure: I’m a linguistics student and not a philosophy one, my only formal experience in philosophy is one epistemology and one applied ethics class
 When I was in my epistemology class, one of the main topics was defining what constitutes “knowledge.” We went over multiple theories, JTB, etc. But to create the parameters of definitions, the professor and textbook would consistently reference interviews. One that was cited the most was a dialogue something like the following:

Interviewer: “Did people in ancient history know that the world was flat?” 
Participant: “Sure!” 
Interview: “But consider that the world isn’t actually flat.” 
Participant: “Okay, then I guess they didn’t know, they just thought they knew”

This was used to establish ‘truth’ as a requisite property for ‘knowledge.’ Similarly, I’ve been reading about philosophy of science, and in the “demarcation problem” of deciding what is/isn’t science, a lot of writers like Martin Gardner have rooted their analyses in how everyday people might apply the word “science.” Fields like cosmology don’t usually engage in experiments, but are usually termed science, ergo any definition of science must be inclusive of non-experimental fields like cosmology.
This strikes me as very odd. In linguistics, we often use bitexts to distinguish word senses. Like in English, “to go” has hundreds of possible translations to French because it’s so polysemous. But philosophers seem to take words like “science” as uniform concepts representing just one sense. In the case of “to know” particularly, I’m not sure some languages even have a good equivalent for the English word. Spanish separates it into saber/conocer, which are different concepts, and I think Korean has even more separate, related terms which would be more unfamiliar to English speakers.
I get that often, we do get good cross-cultural studies which generalize these sorts of questions across languages, and those are valuable. But in a more general sense, I’m not sure why one would bother so closely examining common parlance at all. Like sure, the philosophical definition of “science” shouldn’t be completely unmoored from how people use the word day-to-day. But trying to pin down exactly when people would/should call something “science” and when they shouldn’t seems less like a question of philosophy and more like a (much less interesting) question of semantics. The usage of any particular word is going to change dramatically over time, across communities, and across contexts, even within a language. That seems not ideal as an anchor for your research if you want to create a presumably universal definition (unless you’re specifically interested in cultural differences of thought on a topic). Why isn’t there more discussion about what makes a definition practical for creating taxonomies, or inherent to the concept it describes? Or who knows, maybe there is and I’m just too junior to know it.
Ultimately, even when this kind of analysis is culturally and linguistically aware (and most of the time it's not), it just seems like it's geared to produce linguistic stamp-collecting, not philosophical insights. So what gives?

This is a good question for this SE, I hope you get good answers. My terse answer is: it is ego, people cling to their interpretations and defend them rather than aiming to learn.

I don't really understand the question. Suppose I have the same perception in mind, of a bird, and I know the word for "bird" in several languages. What do I know? I know the contents of my own associative memories! Suppose I know the concept of flat, and I know the perception of earth, and I believe the earth is flat. Also, I know the meaning of true or not-true. I know a philosopher can assert that only true propositions constitute knowledge. But then how does one evaluate true or false propositions without knowledge of the word-associations or associative memories? It is mission impossible!

The most charitable gloss on it is the following implicit conception. Some terms got historically attached to philosophically essential but not fully understood concepts to be explicated. Cultural variations and fine distinctions are pragmatic and philosophically uninteresting, so can be ignored. Folk intuitions reflect generational experience with these concepts and are valuable for getting to their hidden cores. The interview fragment is a caricature standing in for studies with speakers consistently agreeing to switch from "A knows X" to "A thinks A knows X" once told about X being false.

This said, your objection is almost exactly the motivation for the negative program of experimental philosophy. "Socrates typically expects, and receives, agreement from his interlocutor. Nor does Socrates ask his interlocutor, “What is your conception of knowledge”... Rather, he seems to expect a global answer about what knowledge is. In addition, he seems to expect that knowledge has a single nature... Experimental philosophy uses empirical work to challenge this traditional philosophical project."

Is your question essentially: "Why do we get caught up in semantics in (philosphical) discussion?"

Essentially, yes. But more specifically about why people attach philosophical definitions to common usage

How could 'definitional disputes' not rely on the particulars of language? Here, for instance, how do you define either 'definitional' or 'disputes'?
If you see me as pedantic, why not define 'reliance' or 'particulars' or, come to that, 'language'?
Failing that, are you not simply repeating the ancient idea that all arguments fall down to linguistic definition?

I think it is helpful to grasp that when philosophers examine concepts such as knowledge, what they are doing is analysis rather than just looking for definitions. So your question can be broken into two parts. The first is: why do many philosophers consider analysis to be a useful activity? The second is: is there any value in analysing the concept of knowledge?
Analysis has many aspects. It may be decompositional. It may be reductive. It may involve an attempt to identify the fundamental or essential features of a concept. It may involve an attempt to interpret or elucidate a concept.
Analysis lies at the heart of much intellectual activity. Not just within philosophy, but in science as well. If we have a complex, difficult problem, it is often a good idea to decompose it into constituent parts. This may involve trying to identify fundamental constituents of the problem, i.e. logical or physical atoms. We can then work out how these fundamental components interact with each other and arrive at explanations of some aspect of the world. Hopefully these explanations are illuminating and have value in expanding our knowledge and understanding.
A philosophical example is the concept of causality. Scientists use causal language, so do ordinary people in everyday language, and so do philosophers. But the usage of causal language lacks consistency. Sometimes we speak of events causing other events. The brick hit the window and caused it to break. Sometimes we speak of properties of a thing causing other properties. Water is highly polar and this causes it to be a good solvent for polar molecules. Sometimes we speak of events being caused by an absence. The flowers died because nobody watered them. Sometimes we speak of causes in a non-specific way. Smoking causes lung cancer. Sometimes we speak of people causing events. Sometimes we speak of chains of causes and distinguish ultimate and proximate causes. Sometimes we speak of causal factors and divide up a causal explanation into component parts.
It makes sense to want to understand what causality is because it is important. It matters to engineering. It is in important part of decision theory, and so it plays a role in economics and politics. It features in the application of law, because people are considered to be responsible for the forseeable causal consequences of their actions.
Similarly, knowledge is an important concept. A professor once told me that every language in the world has at least one word for 'know' or 'knowledge'. Such ubiquity would be strange if it didn't matter. At the least, it seems important to distinguish between knowledge and mere belief. If a person claims to know something then others may act on that information, and those actions may have important consequences. As with causality, there are moral and legal implications related to what a person knows or what a person might be expected to know. Sometimes, "I didn't know," is exculpatory and sometimes not, but in either case, we need to understand what knowledge means.
This is why some philosophers engage in the analysis of knowledge. Folk usage of the term is a starting point and may provide some data. Cultural and linguistic variations may be unimportant. Critical enquiry also engages with scientific knowledge and aims at a more complete understanding.
